# Android Emulator two finger scroll laggy on Macbook

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation

on scrolling with two finger on MBP it is laggy swipe is not working perfectly
even though in all other places scrolling works fine
i have a high end laptop no issues with performance

may be i need to turn some settings on i guess please help
currently on mac OS big Sur